# Separate slideshow items to 2 banners when resize from desktop to mobile and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help. Developing web site on Opnecart and should add two banners desktop version and customize it to slideshow when switch to mobile version. Need help on CSS and JS code side

[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s2rB.jpg)

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7mWy.jpg)

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="../new/image/catalog/kontur.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="../new/image/catalog/pilsa.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> // dots for carousel dots
</div>
```

Comment: Both the images are same. Correct them please so that we will get to know what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: my bad. now i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// First calculate the vw of your device
const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);

// Conditionalize the banner div accordingly
if (vw < 600) { // For mobile
   document.getElementbyId("banner").innerHTML = `<div></div>`; // Put the carousel element here
} else {
   document.getElementbyId("banner").innerHTML = `<div></div>`; // Put the element with 2 banners side-by-side
}
```

What this code is doing is it is replacing content in "banner div" according to the mobile/desktop version by inserting elements directly in to the DOM.